# Unable to see status bar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, statusbar

I was just trying to create a window with Status bar and I am not able to see the status bar with as simple code as below. Could anyone tell me what could be the cause? or is it happening only in machine! I restarted VS and also my machine.
I am using VS2013 Express edition

```
<Window x:Class="TemplateBindingSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    </StatusBar>
    <Label>StatusBar Example</Label>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the Label outside of StatusBar. A statusbar without Child cannot be seen, since the ActualHeight would be 0. To solve the problem, put the Label inside the StatusBar.

```
<DockPanel>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Label>StatusBar Example</Label>
    </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I copied the code from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/393ac5/using-statusbar-in-wpf/

Comment: @AnjeneyaMurthy that code doesn't seem to reflect the screenshot. Go through the other examples or try this one instead: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/statusbar-control/

Answer (score 2):

The StatusBar in your sample is empty and therefore has no height.

If you insert some content it should be displayed. For example:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Label>Status Bar Text</Label>
    </StatusBar>
    <Label>StatusBar Example</Label>
</DockPanel>
```