# A Label inside StatusBar with white foreground and some background is not visible in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, label, statusbar

I want to use a Label inside the StatusBar having a foreground color and any background color over it, but problem comes with that is, Background color is visible ans text with foreground color is not visible.

I have also followed some articles
 1. [Unable to see status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351007/unable-to-see-status-bar/27351037)
 2. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/393ac5/using-statusbar-in-wpf/

and more, but everywhere it is suggested to use TextBlock. even in first link, as label is used inside statusbar, but that was not working.

[image]

You can see the snapshot here. and here's my code,

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StatusBar Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column ="0" Height ="20">
  <Label Content="It's Label"  Foreground="White" Width="239" Background="Blue"></Label>
  <TextBlock Text ="It's TextBlock" Foreground="White" Background="Red"></TextBlock>
</StatusBar>
```

So my question is, am I violating any WPF hierarchy rule or missing something useful information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Height** that you gave to StatusBar is the problem. Label have a **Padding** by default. So the height given in StatusBar is not enough for the Label to show its Content. Remove the Height in StatusBar to solve the problem. Also set Padding as 0 to override the default Padding of Label. The modified code looks like below,

```
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Content="It's Label"
               Foreground="White"
               Width="239"
               Padding="0"
               Background="Blue"></Label>
        <TextBlock Text="It's TextBlock"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Background="Red"></TextBlock>
    </StatusBar>
```

Comment: Thanks, It solved the problem. I need to look for the layout now.
But still, I would like to know, Why this is not the same reason for TextBlock ?

Comment: Default padding for textblock is 0.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please mark this answer as the solution :)